# How to fix this memory error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After googling it, I think it is a memory leak but I do not know how to fix this.

Assertion failed: TLS Allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD, underlying allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD has unfreed allocations, size 1528

Im Using Unity 2018.1.0.0f2.

Here is the script that causes the error (Sorry for my awful code organization skills, new to world generation)

```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;
public class WorldGeneration : MonoBehaviour {

public float GenerationDelay;
public float RoomPicker;
public float LevelNumber;

public float RoomCount;
public float MaxRoomCount;
public float LevelSample1Rooms;
public float MaxLevelSample1Rooms;
public float LevelSample2Rooms;
public float MaxLevelSample2Rooms;
public float LevelSample3Rooms;
public float MaxLevelSample3Rooms;
public float LevelSample4Rooms;
public float MaxLevelSample4Rooms;
public float LevelSample5Rooms;
public float MaxLevelSample5Rooms;


public GameObject LevelSample1;
public GameObject LevelSample2;
public GameObject LevelSample3;
public GameObject LevelSample4;
public GameObject LevelSample5;

public Transform SpawnLevelPoint;

public Transform SpawnLevelPoint1;
public bool Leveloadedatpoint1;
public Transform SpawnLevelPoint2;
public bool Leveloadedatpoint2;
public Transform SpawnLevelPoint3;
public bool Leveloadedatpoint3;
public Transform SpawnLevelPoint4;
public bool Leveloadedatpoint4;
public Transform SpawnLevelPoint5;
public bool Leveloadedatpoint5;
public Transform SpawnLevelPoint6;
public bool Leveloadedatpoint6;

void Start()
{

    StartCoroutine("Createpoint1room");
}

public IEnumerator Createpoint1room()
{
    if (Leveloadedatpoint1 == false)
    {


        RoomPicker = Random.Range(1, 20);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
        if (RoomPicker == 1 || RoomPicker == 2 || RoomPicker == 3 || RoomPicker == 4 || RoomPicker == 5)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint1 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample1Rooms < MaxLevelSample1Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample1Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample1, SpawnLevelPoint1.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint1 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint1room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint1room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 6 || RoomPicker == 7 || RoomPicker == 8)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint1 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample2Rooms < MaxLevelSample2Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample2Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample2, SpawnLevelPoint1.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint1 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint1room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint1room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 9 || RoomPicker == 10 || RoomPicker == 11)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint1 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample3Rooms < MaxLevelSample3Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample3Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample3, SpawnLevelPoint1.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint1 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint1room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint1room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 12 || RoomPicker == 13 || RoomPicker == 14)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint1 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample4Rooms < MaxLevelSample4Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample4Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample4, SpawnLevelPoint1.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint1 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint1room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint1room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 15 || RoomPicker == 16 || RoomPicker == 17)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint1 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample5Rooms < MaxLevelSample5Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample5Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample5, SpawnLevelPoint1.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint1 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint1room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint1room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 18 || RoomPicker == 19 || RoomPicker == 20)
        {
            StartCoroutine("Createpoint1room");
        }

        Debug.Log("Point 1: The number is " + RoomPicker);
    }
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
    }
}
public IEnumerator Createpoint2room()
{
    if (Leveloadedatpoint2 == false)
    {
        RoomPicker = Random.Range(1, 20);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
        if (RoomPicker == 1 || RoomPicker == 2 || RoomPicker == 3 || RoomPicker == 4 || RoomPicker == 5)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint2 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample1Rooms < MaxLevelSample1Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample1Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample1, SpawnLevelPoint2.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint2 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 6 || RoomPicker == 7 || RoomPicker == 8)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint2 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample2Rooms < MaxLevelSample2Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample2Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample2, SpawnLevelPoint2.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint2 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 9 || RoomPicker == 10 || RoomPicker == 11)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint2 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample3Rooms < MaxLevelSample3Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample3Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample3, SpawnLevelPoint2.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint2 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 12 || RoomPicker == 13 || RoomPicker == 14)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint2 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample4Rooms < MaxLevelSample4Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample4Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample4, SpawnLevelPoint2.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint2 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 15 || RoomPicker == 16 || RoomPicker == 17)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint2 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample5Rooms < MaxLevelSample5Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample5Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample5, SpawnLevelPoint2.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint2 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 18 || RoomPicker == 19 || RoomPicker == 20)
        {
            StartCoroutine("Createpoint2room");
        }

        Debug.Log("Point 2: The number is " + RoomPicker);
    }
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
    }
}
public IEnumerator Createpoint3room()
{
    if (Leveloadedatpoint3 == false)
    {
        RoomPicker = Random.Range(1, 20);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
        if (RoomPicker == 1 || RoomPicker == 2 || RoomPicker == 3 || RoomPicker == 4 || RoomPicker == 5)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint3 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample1Rooms < MaxLevelSample1Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample1Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample1, SpawnLevelPoint3.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint3 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 6 || RoomPicker == 7 || RoomPicker == 8)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint3 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample2Rooms < MaxLevelSample2Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample2Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample2, SpawnLevelPoint3.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint3 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 9 || RoomPicker == 10 || RoomPicker == 11)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint3 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample3Rooms < MaxLevelSample3Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample3Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample3, SpawnLevelPoint3.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint3 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 12 || RoomPicker == 13 || RoomPicker == 14)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint3 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample4Rooms < MaxLevelSample4Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample4Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample4, SpawnLevelPoint3.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint3 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 15 || RoomPicker == 16 || RoomPicker == 17)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint3 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample5Rooms < MaxLevelSample5Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample5Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample5, SpawnLevelPoint3.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint3 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 18 || RoomPicker == 19 || RoomPicker == 20)
        {
            StartCoroutine("Createpoint3room");
        }

        Debug.Log("Point 3: The number is " + RoomPicker);
    }
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
    }
}
public IEnumerator Createpoint4room()
{
    if (Leveloadedatpoint4 == false)
    {
        RoomPicker = Random.Range(1, 20);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
        if (RoomPicker == 1 || RoomPicker == 2 || RoomPicker == 3 || RoomPicker == 4 || RoomPicker == 5)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint4 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample1Rooms < MaxLevelSample1Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample1Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample1, SpawnLevelPoint4.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint4 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint5room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 6 || RoomPicker == 7 || RoomPicker == 8)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint4 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample2Rooms < MaxLevelSample2Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample2Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample2, SpawnLevelPoint4.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint4 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint5room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 9 || RoomPicker == 10 || RoomPicker == 11)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint4 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample3Rooms < MaxLevelSample3Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample3Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample3, SpawnLevelPoint4.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint4 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint5room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 12 || RoomPicker == 13 || RoomPicker == 14)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint4 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample4Rooms < MaxLevelSample4Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample4Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample4, SpawnLevelPoint4.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint3 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 15 || RoomPicker == 16 || RoomPicker == 17)
        {
            if (Leveloadedatpoint3 == false)
            {
                if (LevelSample5Rooms < MaxLevelSample5Rooms)
                {
                    LevelSample5Rooms += 1;
                    Instantiate(LevelSample5, SpawnLevelPoint4.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Leveloadedatpoint3 = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint5room");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
            }
        }
        if (RoomPicker == 18 || RoomPicker == 19 || RoomPicker == 20)
        {
            StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
        }

        Debug.Log("Point 4: The number is " + RoomPicker);
    }
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine("Createpoint4room");
    }
}
public IEnumerator Createpoint5room()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GenerationDelay);
    Debug.Log("Generation finished");
}
}
```

Edit1: 
This error also seems to crash my Editor and crashes the build of the game as well.

Comment: I am having the same problem, I think it is because of Coroutines.

Comment: Troubled minds think alike?

Comment: Just added the correct answer for this, see below now, tks me later !-)

Comment: Normally this assert means Unity alloced memory which should be dealloced at this frame, but somehow it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting tons of `Stack allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD has unfreed allocations, size ...` messages. Which is almost, but not exactly the same message you're getting, but that might be because of the different Unity version (I'm on 2018.2.9).

But as described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/65419d/tls_allocator_alloc_temp_thread_underlying/dl9gcv3), simply restarting Unity fixed it for me.

Comment: I think this is an indirect error caused by having a memory leak somewhere in the code, or in my case a stack overflow. Restarting Unity3D cleared it up, and in my case I'd already eliminated the cause.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is really simple and doesn't require the restart of Unity. Just go to preferences and under GI tab, hit Clean Cache button. No more errors for you !-)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Unity 2019.4

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Unity 2021, I tried the Clean Cache method and restarted Unity. The memory error was gone but some new warnings about missing referenced script showed up.